# how to write a script using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I want to make a page where the user can insert a url and when they click the button their image will appear on the page. But as the code stands now, when a user inserts their url, it displays the url and not the image. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

```
    <script>
        function start() {
            var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
                button.onclick = buttonClick;
        }
        window.onload = start;

        function buttonClick() {
            var imageLinkInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
            var imageLink = imageLinkInput.value;
            if (imageLink == "") {
                alert("Please enter an image");
            }
            else {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = imageLink;


                var ul = document.getElementById("images");
                ul.appendChild(li);


                imageInput.value = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="imageInput" size="40" placeholder="Enter Image">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Image">
    <ul id="images"></ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new Image element ("img") and add it to the unordered list:

```
    <script>
        function start() {
            var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
                button.onclick = buttonClick;
        }
        window.onload = start;

        function buttonClick() {
            var imageLinkInput = document.getElementById("imageInput");
            var imageLink = imageLinkInput.value;
            if (imageLink == "") {
                alert("Please enter an image");
            }
            else {
                var ul = document.getElementById( 'images' );
                var li = document.createElement( 'li' );

                // create image tag here and set source
                var img = document.createElement( 'img' );
                img.src = imageLink;

                li.appendChild( img );
                ul.appendChild( li );

                imageInput.value = '';
            }
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="imageInput" size="40" placeholder="Enter Image">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Image">
    <ul id="images"></ul>
</body>
```

Please see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kukiwon/HDWzz/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the innerHtml of the `li`, create a new `img` element and set it's source and append that to your `li`.

```
var ul = document.getElementById( 'images' );
var li = document.createElement( 'li' );
var img = document.createElement( 'img' );
img.src = imageLink;
li.appendChild( img );
ul.appendChild( li );
imageInput.value = '';
```